# Full Text Search in MongoDB does not find the expected results when using "none" language

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

I am testing a scenario in MongoDB (4.2.1) with full text search with the following documents:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "1", 
    "t" : [
        {
            "t" : "Stadt und Land and Fluss", 
            "language" : "de"
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : "2" 
    "t" : [
        {
            "t" : "City and Country und River", 
            "language" : "en"
        }
    ]
}
```

The text in each language is defined with the language field. Both texts are just sample texts.

Document #1 is in English, but the text contains an German stop word.
Document #2 is in German but the text contains an English stop word.

Now the following happens:

#### **Scenario 1**: Search by stopword with default language.

`{ $text: { $search: "and" } } // Returns NOTHING`

I get nothing back, because it seems to use the English stopwords.

BUT if I use the german stopword I only get the English back.

`{ $text: { $search: "und" } } // Returns 1`

#### **Scenario 2**: Search by stopword with "none" language

If I use the English stopword I get the German document back and vice versa.

`{ $text: { $search: "and", $language: "none" } } // Returns 2`

`{ $text: { $search: "und", $language: "none" } } // Returns 1`

#### **Scenario 3**: Search by "normal" word with default language

This works as expected:

`{ $text: { $search: "City" } } // Returns 1`

`{ $text: { $search: "Stadt" } } // Returns 2`

#### **Scenario 3**: Search by "normal" word with "none" language

Now it becomes really strange when I search for words in the English text.

`{ $text: { $search: "City", $language: "none" } } // Returns NOTHING`

It works for the words in the German document:

`{ $text: { $search: "Stadt", $language: "none" } } // Returns 2`

The word itself does not matter.

I just want MongoDB to respect my language and stop words. It also does not matter whether I create a nested document or not, the behavior is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

It's working as intended, but the documentation is greatly misleading.

TL;DR **don't** search with $language:"none" on a text index with language other than none. This will search for non-stemmed words inside a stemmed index, and most likely fail.

I have already filed an issue regarding MongoDB doc, but until now it has not been updated:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-13175

Using **$language** in a text search with a **different value than the index's default_language** can lead to very unexpected results, including **not finding exact matches** (even without diacritics).

In most cases you **should not specify a different language than the default**, unless you know exactly how the stemmers work for each languages used.

Incidentally, "default_language" is also misleading (but correctly documented) since it not only sets a default language for search queries but also defines once and for all how text is indexed, with stemming and stop words.

A simple example:

```
db.test.insert({t: "bats"})
db.test.createIndex({t:"text"})
db.test.countDocuments({"$text":{"$search":"bats", "$language":"none"}});
-> 0
```

How does text search tranforms input?

- indexing a value: 1) stemming 2) remove diacritics, using index language
- search term: 1) stemming 2) remove diacritics, using search language

ex w/ english:

```
passes => pass => pass
passés => passé => passe
```

ex w/ french:

```
passes => pass => pass
passés => pass => pass
```

ex w/ language none (no stemming):

```
passes => passes
passés => passes
```